# Malber TD 700 dryer not turning on

Tags: repair, dryer, appliances

I have a stackable washer dryer - the dryer is a Malber TD 700 and is stacked on top of the washing machine.

The other day I used the dryer without any problems in the morning. I tried it again about an hour later, and it wouldn't turn on. Usually when the on button is pressed it stays depressed and a light goes on, but now the button will not stay down, and the light does not turn on.

Here is what I looked at: The outlet seems to be working fine, for other appliances. I tried unplugging the dryer for a while (overnight) but that also did not solve the problem.
Another thought I had was that the problem was with the mechanism that recognizes the door is closed. I tried reaching in to manually press that, and I got the machine to turn on for a second. But, further attempts did not lead to any more success, and I do not think that it was really the problem.

Any other ideas of what I may be able to do?

*It was suggested to me to try to check the door switch. How can I do that?

Comment: The door switch is that mechanism you are talking about that recognizes the door is closed. In a whirlpool it is fairly easy to remove, I don't know how to do it in a Malber machine though. I think it is more complicated.

Comment: Since you got it to work kind of I would be looking at the switch also, i don’t know that brand but I would try bypassing the door switch to see if it Is the root cause. The start button not holding down may be there form of a “pull in device” if the door switch breaks the circuit it won’t stay pulled in but that’s just a guess. (When I say bypass the door switch this is for testing not meant to be left in a bypassed condition. 
The other common issue with dryers is a thermal safety fuse. These blow when they get hot many times caused by lint blocking the exhaust line.

Comment: @EdBeal How can I bypass the door switch? Also how can I check the thermal safety fuse?

Comment: Most models the door switch is screwed in and the screw can be removed and the 2 wires jumpered together, you should unplug or turn the breaker off before trying any electrical maintenance. The thermal safety is usually part of the heat/ blower and usually accessible again make sure the power is off. I have worked on us brands like matag,GE, worldpool. They are all similar on the older ones. If you have a ohm meter or continuity tester the fuse should show short or very low resistance if high or open it’s blown. The door switch should change from short or low resistance to open or high resista

Comment: @EdBeal I see. I was able to find youtube videos about opening some of the other modes, but I can't figure this one out! I suppose I'll keep looking :)